# Verificar se existe elemento no array

Tags: javascript

Preciso checar se um nome existe dentro do array e retornar `true` caso encontre ou `false` caso contrário.

```
let names = ["Ana","João","Pedro","Maria"];

function hasName() {
  for (let i=0; i < names.length;i++) {
    if (names === "Pedro") {
      return true;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Bem-vindo ao [pt.so]. Lembre-se de sempre adicionar uma descrição à sua publicação deixando explícito qual sua dificuldade e o que já tentou. Também note que é possível usar formatação de código usando a barra de formatação enquanto você escreve a publicação. Isso torna a publicação mais fácil de ser lida e entendida e, consequentemente, vai te ajudar a ter uma resposta.

Comment: Depois que terminar de fazer esse exercício de uma lida nesse link: [Determinar se um array contém um determinado elemento](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/contains)

Comment: Aproveite e veja também sobre outros métodos como **find**, **some**, **every**.

Answer (score 1):

Você está comparando o conjunto todo usando `names == "Pedro"`. Você deveria usar apenas um elemento `names[i]`.

Veja abaixo funcionando:

```js
let names = ["Ana","João","Pedro","Maria"]
console.log(hasName())

function hasName() {
  for (let i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
    if (names[i] == "Pedro") {
      return true;
    }
  }
}
```